# Cant Understand the arguments in filter [VueJS]

Tags: javascript, vue.js

As I was reading the VueJS [Filter(orderby)](http://vuejs.org/api/#filterBy) API doc
and I find it hard to understand the args.
Below is the sample

```
Arguments:
   {String | Function} targetStringOrFunction
   "in" (optional delimiter)
   {String} [...searchKeys]
```

Any answer is great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [Doc](http://vuejs.org/api/#filterBy) the filter `filterBy` is limited to directives that expect `Array` values, e.g. `v-for`.

And for the args :

- **For targetStringOrFunction arg :**

Assuming that we have an array of strings and you want to filter it according to a value fro an input for example, to achive this goal you can use `filterBy` like this :

```
    new Vue({
    el: '...',

    data: {
        searchedValue: '' // keeping it empty will simply show all results
    }
    ...
});
```

In the HTML :

```
<div v-for="value in values | filterBy searchedValue">
```

You can bind the `searchedValue` to an input to add an effect.

> For the function part see the example below.

- **For `in` and `{String} [...searchKeys]` args :**

Assuming that we have an array of user, and in the user object we have a `firstName` and a `lastName` properties and you want to filter it according to a value, to achive this goal you can use `filterBy` like this :

```
<div v-for="user in users | filterBy searchedValue in 'firstName'">
```

Or you can search in multiple keys :

```
<div v-for="user in users | filterBy searchedValue in 'firstName' 'lastName'">
```

And you can create an function to wrap your code like so :

```
var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: {
        searchedValue: '',

        users: [
          {firstName: 'Jhone', lastName:'Doe'},
          {firstName: 'Daved', lastName:'Bazz'},
          {firstName: 'Pieter', lastName:'Foo'},
        ]
    },
    methods: {
      myFilter: function(user) {
          return user.firstName == searchedValue; //Or what erev you want here
      }
    },
})
```

Hope that hepl :)

Comment: ahh, so the {String | Function} targetStringOrFunction doesn't mean the actual loop itself. 

seems their syntax is just the same because of the `in` keyword

Comment: Yep, the `targetStringOrFunction` is just an explaination of `{String | Function}` :)

Comment: can you accept the answer to help others getting the correct answer ;)